# HTML,CSS: Header appears behind the other content

Tags: html, css, header

I'm trying to do a fixed header but it hides behind the rest of the content on the screen. I've tried to change the z-index but it doesn't work.

My html file looks like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 88px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.first-sec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 608px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.second-sec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 89px;
}
.third-sec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 665px;
}
.fourth-sec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 317px;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.85);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="first-sec">
  </div>
  <div class="second-sec">
  </div>
  <div class="third-sec">
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-sec">
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just adding `    z-index: 2;` or whatever, on `#header` and it works. don't know why you say it doesn't. see here >  https://jsfiddle.net/sLj0v59e/

Comment: When you scroll down, the header appears behind the other content

Comment: forgot to save the fiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/sLj0v59e/1/ this was the link . so, my comment still stands, why did you say that it doesn't work with `z-index` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your header selector like this:

```
.header{
    width:100%;
    height:88px;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: 9;
    background: #009ddc; /* for test */
}
```

It's working.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
.header{
z-index:2 !important;
    width:100%;
    height:88px;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background: gray;
}
```

(the background: gray is only for temporary purposes)

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly well! I had forogt to add a bg-color :)